# How can I merge redundant fields within a structure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a data set with multiple fields of which several of the fields are different names for equivalent properties. I have rescaled and adjusted the data so that the quantities are comparable and want to merge them into a single field.

As a toy example, let's say I have:

```
s = struct('pounds', [nan nan 4.8], 'pennies', [120 370 nan]);
s.pennies = s.pennies/100;
```

How do I merge my incomplete fields to get the desired output:

```
snew = struct(pounds, [1.2 3.7 4.8]);
```

Comment: So what's the desired output in the toy example? Also, what happens if both fields are not `NaN`?

Comment: @LuisMendo edited for clarity to include a desired output for the toy example

Comment: What if two fields have a number (not `NaN`) in the same position? Example: `s = struct('pounds',[nan,nan,4.8], 'pennies', [120,370,340]/100)`

Comment: You could start with a simple `for` loop through the values in both fields, choose from whichever field you want for each element based one some robust logic... I say *robust* because you need to think about the cases Luis pointed out.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear but I do not have such edge cases, I constructed the toy example with this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have modified your field values such that they should be equivalent, and simply need to combine the non-`NaN` values, one option is to [vertically concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) the fields then use [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) or [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) down each column (which will ignore the `NaN` values). Then just remove the unwanted field with [`rmfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmfield.html):

```
>> s = struct('pounds', [nan,nan,4.8], 'pennies', [120,370,nan]);
>> s.pounds = min([s.pounds; s.pennies./100], [], 1);  % Scaling included here
>> s = rmfield(s, 'pennies')

s = 

  struct with fields:

    pounds: [1.2000 3.7000 4.8000]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for **any number of fields**. Since it is guaranteed that **only one field is not `NaN` at each position**, you can

1. Convert to a matrix such that each original field becomes a row of the matrix.
2. Keep only the numbers, ignoring `NaN`'s. By assumption, this gives exactly one number per column.
3. Arrange that into a struct with the desired field name.

```
s = struct('pounds',[nan,nan,4.8], 'pennies', [120,370,nan])
s.pennies = s.pennies/100; % example data
target_field = 'pounds'; % field to which the conversion has been done

t = struct2cell(s); % convert struct to cell array
t = vertcat(t{:}); % convert cell array to matrix
t = t(~isnan(t)).'; % keep only numbers, ignoring NaN's
result = struct(target_field, t); % arrange into a struct
```

Answer (score 0):

try my two-liner below

```
c=struct2cell(s);
s=struct('pounds',unique([c{:}]));
```

even better, you can also do it using the below oneliner

```
s=struct('pounds',unique(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), struct2cell(s),'UniformOutput',false)))')
```